# Hello , I am having a Issue with Website Links connectivity through Database,

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a issue with website links connectivity through database, website is working but links are not working. Every link is getting redirected to Home page,  Website code in **PHP** and Database is **Mysql**, how to connect links from database? website is www.stamod.com

Comment: basically i have changed hosting of website from whois to godaddy , it was working perfectly fine on whois , but same backup is uploaded on godaddy then also links are not working , so is this issue from database?? database is also connected, but links are not getting fetched

Answer (score -1):

LOL, I wonder if your question is even valid, all I see someone trying to mine from that site with the visitor's PCs.

CoinHive.User('BQey5NM18Qz6T1Xak3QNJNxpp3uFUg4m', 'hexm4n');

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured your db credentials in your DBConnectivity file.

e.g - Database name, Username, Password.

Go to Mysql Databases in Godaddy Cpanel and check your credentials. if not configured, create new database from cpanel and import your file accordingly.